# Javascript onmouseover event working but need to reverse upon mouse "not over"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onmouseover

So I have:

```
<img src="image1.png" 
     width="300" 
     height="115" 
     onmouseover="this.src='image1.png';" 
     onmouseout="image2.png">
```

This is working great, but once I hover and the second image turns on, I need it to turn off when I remove the cursor. Any way to achieve this with the simple inline JS I have?

Comment: I think you are looking for mouseOut (Jquery)
https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/
Edit : I can't see your example

Comment: <code><img src="image1.png" width="300" height="115" onmouseover="this.src='image1.png';" onmouseout="image2.png"></code>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just undo the change in the same way by setting the src:

```
<img src="image1.png" width="300" height="115" onmouseover="this.src='image2.png';" onmouseout="this.src='image1.png';">
```

Comment: Sorry everyone, I really bungled up this post, BUT this worked great! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery and use the [.hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) function.  This function performs both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` functions for you so you only need to specify what should happen.

Also, you should specify your styling in a CSS file.

This solution does not supply you with an inline solution, but does reduce your code and separates your concerns.

This is your Javascript.  I've used changing text in a div to show you an example rather than toggling an image, because I don't have an image handy, but it should be simple to use this as an example.

```js
$("#hoverExample").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).text("Mouse has entered");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).text("Mouse has left");
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="hoverExample">Hover over this div</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that inline?

Comment: @ChadF: Nice example! (No need for jsFiddle, we have Stack Snippets now for HTML/CSS/JS questions and answers. It's the `<>` button in the toolbar. [It's not perfect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239706/134069), but it's a step forward.)

Comment: @user8689: Yes, but only on up-to-date versions of browsers. `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave`. `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` were Microsoft innovations and IE has had them forever; Chrome and Firefox have only added them more recently.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that!  That's awesome.  I added a code snippet for you @user8689